# My StopWatch has wrong nano and millis, but right seconds

Tags: java, time

I've implemented a stopwatch class for my own little library and tested it by executing the following snippet:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        sw.start();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        sw.stop();
        System.out.println(sw.getMilli());
        System.out.println(sw.getDuration().getNano());
        System.out.println(sw.getDuration().getSeconds());
    }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
20
2011600
3
```

You can see that the numbers differ. I checked my StopWatch class round about 10 times, but I cant find mistakes. Can you find them?

**This is my stopwatch-implementation:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.Duration;

public class StopWatch {
    private Instant startDate;
    private Instant stopDate;
    
    public StopWatch() {
        reset();
    }
    
    public void start() {
        if (startDate == null) {
            startDate = Instant.now();
        }
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        if (stopDate == null && startDate != null) {
            stopDate = Instant.now();
        }
    }
    
    public void reset() {
        startDate = null;
        stopDate = null;
    }
    
    public Duration getDuration() {
        if (startDate != null && stopDate != null) {
            return Duration.between(startDate, stopDate);
        }
        
        return null;
    }
    
    public long getMilli() {
        if (startDate != null && stopDate != null) {
            return Duration.between(startDate, stopDate).getNano() / 1000000L;
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are not 100,000 nanoseconds in a millisecond.

Comment: also it could be a matter of integer division since you didn't specify the denominator to be long. use for example / 1000L in getMilli

Comment: Fixed it, but that doesnt seem to be the actual problem. Seconds and the other units still differ.

Comment: Nor are there 1,000 nanoseconds in a millisecond.

Comment: I assume you've read the javadoc for `getNano()` and `getSeconds()` and understand what `getNano()` does?

Comment: Ive read it but I didnt understand it fine. Maybe I should continue using the old time classes...

Comment: A Duration contains two fields. `seconds` is the number of whole seconds in the duration (obviously as it is an integer). `nanos` is the additional number of nanoseconds. It is always less than one second.

Comment: In `getMilli()`, why not just call `getDuration().toMillis()`? That will do the right thing, without you having to hard-code any numbers etc... Basically, it sounds like you shouldn't use `getNano()` anywhere - not in `getMilli()` and not in your `main` method.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I missunderstood how objects of the class Duration work. getNano() does not return the total amount of nanoseconds between a range, but the rest of nanoseconds that do not fit into a whole second. I deleted getDuration() and reimplemented getMilli() like that:

```
public long getMilli() {
    if (startDate != null && stopDate != null) {
        Duration duration = Duration.between(startDate, stopDate);
        long nanos = duration.getSeconds() * 1000000000 + duration.getNano(); 
        return nanos / 1000000;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```